# Windows 7 port 80 problem

Tags: windows-7, iis, tomcat

I want to run Tomcat on port 80.

I changed its port on 80, it fail to bind.
I check IIS, it use 8080(I configured)
Then people said winrm share 80 with iis, I configured that, it used

`HTTP = 5985`

`HTTPS = 5986`

Then I try http://www.cameroncooke.com/2009/01/25/Windows-7-uses-port-80-and-makes-it-impossible-to-install-apache-solution/

It fails.

And the 80 is used by nt-kernal/system, whatever that is?

Who is using port 80 and how I get it to work with Tomcat.

By the way, iis can work on 80. I think Windows 7 must reserve for it, but where it reserve.

Comment: Maybe `http://localhost` shows you something?

Comment: There is nothing, sir.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, nothing is reserved by Windows at all.

If u want to use 80 port for apache with IIS installed (on Windows 7), u just need to open **IIS Manager** -> open **Default Web Site** binding (right click and choose option **Edit Bindings**) and replace port 80 to 81 and press ok. That's all.

**Now about TomCat:**

By the default TomCat uses port **8080**, because it is standard port for all http proxies.

If you want to set TomCat work on 80 port, u need to replace in apache config that it might use port 90 instead of default 80, so now u can setup TomCat work with the 80 port.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\>netstat /?

Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections.

NETSTAT [-a] [-b] [-e] [-f] [-n] [-o] [-p proto] [-r] [-s] [-t] [interval]

  -a            Displays all connections and listening ports.
  -b            Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or
                listening port. In some cases well-known executables host
                multiple independent components, and in these cases the
                sequence of components involved in creating the connection
                or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable
                name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called,
                and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option
                can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient
                permissions.
…
  -n            Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
```

To test this I started Apache on my Vista PC. Then I opened a command prompt with administrator privileges and ran the command:

```
C:\>netstat -abn

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [httpd.exe]
```

You should be able to use the same command to track down what program has grabbed port 80 on your Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Microsoft really doesn't want you to use apache. There's some discussion in it here:

http://www.cameroncooke.com/2009/01/25/windows-7-uses-port-80-and-makes-it-impossible-to-install-apache-solution/